# PayPal integration with PHP not giving approve link

Tags: php, curl, paypal, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate PayPal payment gateway. I get authorization token. Create order call returns order id. But Capture doesn't retun approve link. Can you please help me review the code below and let me know where I go wrong?

```
function authenticate() {
    $ch = false;
    global $api_endpoint, $client_id, $client_secret;

    $http_header = array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    $post_fields = 'grant_type=client_credentials';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_id.":".$client_secret);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($result);
    $access_token = $json->access_token;
    curl_close($ch);
    return $access_token;
}

// Request access token
function getAccessToken() {
    global $auth_api_endpoint, $client_id, $client_secret;

    $data = array(
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    );

    $ch = curl_init($auth_api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_id . ':' . $client_secret);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($http_code === 200) {
        $access_token = json_decode($response, true)['access_token'];
        echo "Access token: " . $access_token . "\n";
    return $access_token;
    } else {
        echo "Failed to get access token: " . $response . "\n";
    }
}

function create_order($access_token) {
    $ch = false;
    $http_header = array
    (
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
        "PayPal-Request-Id: $my_request_id"
    );
    $post_fields = '{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units":
  [
    {
      "reference_id": "$my_reference_id",
      "amount":
      {
        "currency_code": "EUR",
        "value": "10.00"
      }
    }
  ],
  "payment_source":
  {
    "paypal":
    {
      "experience_context":
      {
        "payment_method_preference": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED",
        "payment_method_selected": "PAYPAL",
        "brand_name": "EXAMPLE INC",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "landing_page": "LOGIN",
        "user_action": "PAY_NOW",
        "return_url": "https://mydomain/accept_payment.php",
        "cancel_url": "https://mydomain/cancel_payment.php"
      }
    }
  }
}';
    echo "create_order: access_token: $access_token\n";
    echo "create_order: http_header: ";
    print_r($http_header);
    echo "create_order: post_fields: $post_fields\n";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "create_order: result: ";
    $arr_result = json_decode($result);
    var_dump($arr_result);
    echo "\n";
    curl_close($ch);
    return $arr_result->id;
}
//$access_token = authenticate();
$access_token = getAccessToken();
echo "access_token: ".$access_token."\n";
$order_id = create_order($access_token);

$api_endpoint = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/$order_id";
echo "endpoint: ".$api_endpoint."\n";

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
));

// Execute cURL session and store the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for cURL errors and handle them if necessary
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch);

// Process the response (for example, print it)
echo $response;
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "id": "2H5...815N",
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "status": "PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED",
    "payment_source": {
        "paypal": {}
    },
    "purchase_units": [{
        "reference_id": "d...b",
        "amount": {
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "value": "10.00"
        },
        "payee": {
            "email_address": "sb-...@example.com",
            "merchant_id": "P...6",
            "display_data": {
                "brand_name": "EXAMPLE INC"
            }
        }
    }],
    "create_time": "2023-..-..T14:17:18Z",
    "links": [{
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/2H...5N",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET"
    }, {
        "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=2H...N",
        "rel": "payer-action",
        "method": "GET"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The approval link you are looking for is right there in the response, tagged as rel:payer-action.

However, such links are for old integration patterns that redirect away from your site. You should not redirect away from your site.

Instead, keep your site loaded in the background and use the JS SDK to display an in-context approval window.

You can find a demo here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server
And examples (using node.js for its example backend) in the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/). That backend can of course be implemented in any language, including PHP. The create and capture routes should return/output only JSON data (no HTML or text, i.e. never used print or other debug statements for anything that isn't JSON)

The [integration builder](https://developer.paypal.com/integration-builder/) also has various samples.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll check on this further.